# setup:static-content:deploy need to run for minor php changes?

Tags: magento2

Why do i need to run php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy each time i clear the cache and also running the same command is time consuming.

I enabled apache rewrite! But still why ?

Comment: I had the same issue. Try to delete these folders: `pub/static/frontend/<Vendor>/*`, `var/view_preprocessed/*`,  `var/cache/*`, then set your environment to `developer` with `php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer`. After that Magento will create symlink as KAndy says. Sadly you have to do this each time you change a `.less` file in order to regenerate compiled files. Hope this help you. When you go to production you will need to set the environment to `production` and run `setup:static-content:deploy`.

Comment: i had enabled the developer mode, i deleted the pub static and var view folders, but i am not dealing with .less files, i change the xml files and php code and the css and js does not seem to generate properly in admin which works after i run the content deploy command.

Comment: This unfortunately is happening in only one of my instances, works properly in other instance of magento2

Answer (score 4):

In development, you don't need to run  setup:static-content:deploy at all. Moreover, if you run this command you will break auto update of files on page update because deploy copies files instead of creating symlink